# Neural Network with random weights does not learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I wanted to compare my classifier that used a VGG16 model pretrained on imagenet to how it would have performed if I did not use the imagenet weights, so I loaded the model by using

`model = applications.VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))`

According to the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) using "weights=None" results in randomly initialized weights.

My problem now though is that the neural network always gives the same output, even after training for multiple epochs and trying different learning rates it always predicts all images as the same class.

I do not think the input data (images of 2 different classes) or my code is the problem, because when initializing with the imagenet weights and training on that my classifier learned very well and reached 90% accuracy on the testset.

What could the problem be? Maybe the weight initializtaion? But I don't know how to use a different Initializer when loading the model like that

Comment: What happens if you predefine the weight? Does it still give the same class?

Comment: as you mentioned in your question it always predicts the same class,
your network might have got biased towards that class.
Check that your dataset is properly segregated and have enough data to train from scratch

Comment: @deathangel908 I'm not sure how I do that in Keras when loading in an application.

Comment: @thefifthjack005 I have a 2:1 split of classes in my training data. I have only 360 different examples, but I am using Data Augmentation to artificially increase it. I know this is a very small amount of data, but it worked very well when using the pretrained model

Comment: if you are training in batch check that data from both classes is getting passed as training examples in each batch,so the model is is able to see the data from both the classes at each batch.
My opinion is that it would be hard to train a model with small dataset on vgg from scratch as it has lot of parameters to be optimize.
so prefer fine tuning the model.

Comment: @thefifthjack005 what I find weird is that even with the random weights all predictions are very close to predicting a 0.5000, I would have expected to get more random outcomes with random weights. That's why I want to change the randomness function that generates the random weights

Comment: checks
i assume you might have done most of that already

 1. labels are one hot coded
 2. loss is dropping
 3. create a small CNN network and check if you are facing the same
    issue there
 4. image is centered zero for training
 5. check different weights initialization techniques

you can initialize weights in CONV2D() by passing value to parameter kernel_initializer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing a vanishing gradient problem.

If you use relu activation function, look at "kaiming initialisation" for your weight. The objective is to keep a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1 for your output after each layer during the forward pass.

For relu activation fuction you have to initialize with random normal distribution multiplied by the square root of 2/(number of input for the given layer).

```
weight_initialisation = random_normal * sqrt(2/(number of input for the layer))
```

For CNN, I think the number of input will be number of filter * number of cell in the kernel (or 5 * 5 for a [5, 5] kernel)